# Optimizing RequireJS for HTTP/2: Does modifying a hashed file matter here?

Tags: caching, hash, requirejs, r.js

I am trying to optimize a RequireJS project first for HTTP/2 and SPDY, and secondly for HTTP/1.x. Rather than concatenating all of my RequireJS modules into one big file, I am hacking r.js to resave the modules that would have been concatenated as separate files. This will be better for the new protocols, because each file will be cached individually, and a change to one file won't invalidate the caches of all the other files. For the old protocols, I will pay a penalty in additional HTTP requests, but I can at least avoid *subsequent* rounds of requests by appending revision hashes to my files (i.e. "module.js" becomes "module.89abcdef.js") and setting a long `max-age` on them, so I want to do that.

r.js adds names to previously-anonymous modules. That means that the file "module.js" with this definition:

```
define(function () { ... })
```

Becomes this:

```
define("module.js", function () { ... })
```

I want this, because I will be loading some of my modules via `<script>` elements (to prevent RequireJS HTTP requests acting as a bottleneck to dependency resolution; I can instead utilize r.js's topological sorting to generate `<script>` elements which the browser can start loading as soon as it parses them). However, I also plan to load some modules dynamically (i.e., via RequireJS's programmatic insertion of `<script>` elements). This means RequireJS may at some point request a module via a URL.

Here is the problem I have run into: I am generating a RequireJS `map` configuration object to map my modules' original module IDs to their revision-hashed module IDs, so that when RequireJS loads a module dynamically, it requests the revision-hashed file name. But the modules it loads, which are now named modules thanks to r.js, have the *un-revisioned* name of the module, because I don't revision the files until after I minify them, which I only do after r.js generates them (thus r.js doesn't know about the revisions).

So the file "module.89abcdef.js" contains the module:

```
define("module.js", function () { ... })
```

When these named modules execute, `define` will register a module with the wrong name. When other modules require "module.js", this name will be mapped to "module.89abcdef.js" (thanks to the `map` configuration), but since a module with that name was not actually defined after the `onload` event of a `<script>` with the `src` attribute "module.89abcdef.js" fired, the module they receive is `undefined`.

To be faithful to the new file name, the file "module.89abcdef.js" should probably instead contain the definition:

```
define("module.89abcdef.js", function () { ... })
```

So, I believe the solution to my problem will be to replace the unrevisioned name of the module in the r.js-generated file with the revisioned name. However, this means the hash of the file is now invalidated. **My question: In this situation, does it matter that the hash of the file is invalid?**

I think it's impossible that the module name in the source code *could* be faithful to the file name, because if the module name had a hash, well, then the hash of the file would be different, so the module name would become the new hash, and so on recursively.

I fear there might be a case where the unfaithful hash would cause the file to still be cached even when it'd actually changed, but I cannot think of one. It seems that appending the same hash for the file's original contents to the file's name and the module's name should always still result in a unique file.

(My lengthy explanation is an attempt to eliminate certain "workaround"-type answers. If I weren't loading modules dynamically, then I wouldn't need to use `map` and I wouldn't have a file-name-vs-module-name mismatch; but I do load modules dynamically, so that workaround won't work. I also believe I would not need to revision files if I were only serving clients on newer protocols [I could just use ETags as there would be no additional overhead to make the comparison], but I do serve clients on the older protocols, so that workaround doesn't work either. And finally, I don't want to run r.js after revisioning files, because I only want to revision after minifying the files, in case minification maps two sources to the same output, in which case I could avoid an unnecessary cache invalidation.)